# Woodburning stove ENCORE Model 1450 - where is the air intake?

Tags: chimney, air, woodstove

I have pretty old woodburning stove ENCORE Non-Catalytic Model 1450(by Vermont Castings). It suddenly (a week ago) stopped burning wood well, it looks like it does not get enough air in. Its air control regulator on the right-hand side is set to HighHeat (as always was), the damper is open when starting fire - so no changes, however it just does not burn, and fire goes out. I examined all around the stove, and can't seem to find where is tre air intake controlled by the AirControl regulator? If I can find it, at least I could clean it, vacuum, may be that would help with my problem.

Comment: Could be something shifted in the chimey, blocking the draft. Inspect it. Could be things covered under "spring cleaning" pages 30-32 or so of the manual. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/186195/Vermont-Castings-Encore-1450.html?page=32#manual

Comment: @Ecnerwal, I had chimney sweepers just couple of days ago to clean the chimney, they didn't find anything wrong with the chimney itself.

Comment: Good that you have checked. It's one common cause. The manual (and not having a stove to look at) makes the actual air intake path less than clear, but it would make sense that it's going though the area they suggest you vacuum out in the back of the stove while the flue is off - not quite as obvious as ye olde Vigilant with obvious holes, but similar general concept, just updated from that old thing.

Comment: Could observing the effect on combustion of leaving the door ajar indicate whether the fault is in the exhaust flue or in the normal combustion air inlet vents? Perhas some mechanical connection has gotten detached and the combustion air inlet vents are remaining closed or nearly closed. Or would leaving the door ajar just allow smoke out and be inconclusive?